# Json Deserialisation with subarrays doesn't contain values

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, json.net

I am trying to deserialise a json object. The Problem is that the the object also contains subarrays
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGuQt.png

Except for the subarrays everything is working.

I am using Newtonsoft.Json;

Here is my class

```
    public string date_updated { get; set; }
    public string date_expires { get; set; }
```

This is working fine.

For the subarray I did it that way:

```
    public JsonArray contacts { get; set; }
```

This is my method to deserialise it:

```
            var json = await webClient.GetAsync(new Uri(uri));
            var result = await json.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(result);
```

The Array is created well with all fields needed, but the values are not working.
The values are just: Windows.Json.JsonObject as on the picture below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UX0NK.png

Why is he not writing the values? How can I get them?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is best done with a `contact` class in c# and having contacts as a `List<contact>` or `contact[]`. If no one types up a full answer I'll give it a go later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values are working fine. Using JsonArray tells the deserializer to convert the JSON data to something that is compatible with the type JsonArray. This type is simply a 1:1 representation of the JSON string underneath and is not deserialized into useful data automatically for you.

Also, JsonArray is not even part of the Json.Net library. As the debugger is telling you, it is part of the Windows.Data.Json namespace which is in a different library. You could still access the data directly from each JsonObjects using the various Get methods inside the class ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.data.json.jsonobject.aspx ) but this is probably not the way you want to go.

In your case, you should create a class that represents the data you have inside each of those arrays. If not all entries in the array contains all of the properties of your class, don't worry. Json.Net will simply leave their value empty when deserializing. This will look like:

```
public class Contact
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string organization { get; set; }
    public string full_address { get; set; }

    etc.
}
```

For good measure, you should also respect the C# naming convention which states that properties should use CamelCase names. To help you with this, you can use the JsonProperty attribute like so:

```
public class Contact
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("organization")]
    public string Organization { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("full_address")]
    public string FullAddress { get; set; }

    etc.
}
```

Then, you can replace the type of your `contacts` property to `List<Contact>` and the data will be automatically deserialized to a format that you can easily use.

Comment: I thought you'd like to know why things where happening and not just how to fix them ;)

Comment: I do, that why I liked your detailed comment! Good work! Great community :)

Answer (score 1):

Define new class

```
class Contact {
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    // etc
}
```

and modify your `ReqInfo_WhoIs_Model` class

```
public string date_updated { get; set; }
public string date_expires { get; set; }
public List<Contact> contacts { get; set; }
```